# python script start on reboot failed

Tags: python

I have a python script on a raspberry pi which i wanted to run on start up. I have created a start up file to run and it seems to startup my script but then the script fails. 
I can run the script from the terminal when logged in and it works ok. 
Below is what I get back from the failed start

```
● myscript.service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myscript.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-01-13 11:20:14 UTC; 1min 27s ago
  Process: 371 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/python/request.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 371 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi python[371]: return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi python[371]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi python[371]: resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi python[371]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi python[371]: r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi python[371]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi python[371]: raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi python[371]: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: myscript.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 13 11:20:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit myscript.service entered failed state.
```

My python script uses request to connect to the intenet which is below

```
import requests
import wiringpi2
import time

wiringpi2.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi2.pinMode(17,1)

wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,1)

def delay ():
        #wait here for a while
        counter = 0
        while counter < 40:
                counter += 1
                #recheck web text file if now "o" then turn water off end delay
                request = requests.get('http://stevesolarhome.com/WaterControl.txt')
                #if still reading "1" then carry on with delay
                if request.text == "1":
                        time.sleep(3)
                elif request.text == "0":
                        counter = 401
        #delay timed out update web to turn water off
        #send update to text file
        payload = {'status':'0'}
        r = requests.get("http://stevesolarhome.com/water/water.php/get", params = payload)
        wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,1)
        #digitalWrite turn water off

while 1:
        request = requests.get('http://stevesolarhome.com/WaterControl.txt')
        if request.text == "1":
                wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,0)
                delay ()
```

Can anyone help. Do you need the start up script. I was following the below tutorial for this 
http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/

Comment: Did you try running it with superuser privileges?

Comment: to run it from the terminal I have to use sudo in front of the script. how can i run it as superuser from start up

Comment: Can you run the file **without** sudo normally (not on start up)?

Comment: `Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.` The complete error messages may help

Comment: Also check on `start-stop-daemon`

Comment: the program is correct its only that you re trying to connect to the internet while the system hasnt got the the network interface ready,it basically connecting on nothing ,the solution is the check if the network adapter is ready before connecting  instead connecting and wait for the response ,that i dont know ,also check this link http://superuser.com/questions/693514/systemd-service-will-start-manually-but-not-at-boot

Comment: What is the file starting the script? What does this mean: /usr/bin/python sudo /home/pi/python/request.py? Why there is a sudo between python and the script name?

Comment: put the -l in and i cant work out why it is failing when it works ok from the terminal. There should not be the sudo between the lines /usr/bin/python sudo /home/pi/python/request.py?. This was my attempt to run it as sudo

Comment: test@testVM ~]$ python sudo test.py
python: can't open file 'sudo': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: no i need sudo to run from the terminal.

Comment: Yes you need, but why do you put sudo in the middle between python and your script? This makes no sense to me and I have showed you that this is wrong.

Comment: sorry this was a mistake i was putting this in to try get the script to start with sudo. I have removed this and it still will not work. i have edited the question and added the full error message that i am still getting

Comment: you get an "raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)" . your script is not handling ConnectionError exceptions at all. You should modify your code to check if connection can be established and  try again if not. Simply try your script on the console with network turned off and you will see where your pain is.

Comment: this is the script that is suppose to run on start up. It is suppose to wait for all systems to be running before running the python script. 'code'   Description=My Script Service  
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/python/request.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
'code'     the script does not have any connection errors when run from terminal

Answer (score 1):

Simply do because the python interpreter will treat sudo as file wich is not the case:

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/python/request.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is wrong.

On startup

```
/usr/bin/python sudo /home/pi/python/request.py
```

is executed (which fails of course) since python tries to execute a `sudo` file.

You want instead

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/python/request.py
```

as startup scripts are normally executed under the root user (if not specified
otherwise in your `.service` file).